# How to run another file using command prompt and continue with the rest of steps without waiting for the file to be closed

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I came across a strange scenario where it works intermittently.

**Requirement:**

Need to back date the system date before running a file and once the file is ran the system date should be reverted to the current date.

I have written a code which works for one of the file and doesn't work for other files.What happens is the code captures the current `dd mm and yyyy` values into variables and and backdates the system date,opens a file and waits for the file to be closed before automatically reverting the date to the current date.

I wanted to leave the file open and get the date set to the current date automatically rather than waiting for the file to be closed.

**Issue:**

The file opened through the bat file should be closed to continue with the rest of the steps in the code.

The call command with & worked for one of the exe as mentioned in the rem of the code below ,but doesn't seem to be working for others.

Please save the below code as `Test.bat` file to execute.

**Code written:**

```
    @For /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @( 
        Set Month=%%B
        Set Day=%%A
        Set Year=%%C
    )
    @echo DAY = %Day%
    @echo Month = %Month%
    @echo Year = %Year%

    @echo "Current date is " %Day%_%Month%_%Year%

    date 01/06/2008

    @echo "Date changed to old date successfully"

    rem call C:\Users\ARUN\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe &

    call D:\set_date.txt &

    date %Day%/%Month%/%Year%

    @echo "Date changed to current year successfully"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start is the command you want

```
start "" "C:\windows\notepad.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Serenity ..it worked.I was trying strat /b and start /min earlier but not start..it worked now :)